# Extracting responseJSON object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am fairly new to ajax and Javascript
I have this code

```
duration_reco = $.ajax({
    url : newurl, 
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function (obj) {});

console.log(duration_reco);
```

The output I get is http://grab.by/v0lc
I am interested in the responseJSON(last object  in the snapshot). I have tried duration_reco.responsejSON, but it doesnt work. How can I get the vlue.

## Edit

Just providing more code, so that you can help better

```
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) 
{   
    duration_reco = $.ajax({
        url : newurl, 
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function (obj) {
        console.log(obj.data.duration); 
        //console.log(duration_reco.responseJSON());
        data[i - 1] = {
            "duration" : obj.data.duration
         };
     });
}
```

I tried to do something like this, but it seems neither 'i' nor 'data' is accessible inside. What are my other options

Comment: `.done(function (obj) {console.log(duration_reco);});`

Comment: See "[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)"

Comment: If you can provide more code (like, what do you want to do before and after this call) then someone (maybe me) will show you how to do it asynchronously and beautifully. Asynchronous is _good_. Provide more code.

Answer (score 2):

Your Ajax request is being done asynchronously, while your code is being executed linearly.  You need to log the output in the callback function.

```
var duration_reco = {};

$.ajax({
    url : newurl, 
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function (obj) {
  duration_reco = obj;
  console.log(duration_reco);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to make synchronous requests. How can I do it?

Comment: it can be found in the documentation (the async param).  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  Though it is preferable to make your code non-blocking by making it async.

Answer (score 0):

You have access in the `.done` function where `obj` is the parameter.

```
}).done(function (obj) {
    //console.log(obj); //your response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In comments here and there throughout this question you have said things like "I want to make it synchronous" and "can I access it outside". You are encountering one of the very common problems a learner will encounter when working with asynchronous code. You are exasperated because you want to write code like this:

1. set up the call
2. make the call
3. deal with the results

Asynchronous requests, you feel, are just getting in the way. Don't feel this way! Don't get frustrated: learn about the problem and then get even. Here is a link to a great resource that can help you [tame asynchronous code](http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript).

**Edit**: using the sample code you provided, I've crafted a minimal example of how you would set this all up with promises. Check out the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg95v/1/).

```
// global variables: find a better way!
var data = [];
var count = 0;

// a function that returns a promise can be "waited for"
var many_requests = function () {
    var promise = $.Deferred();

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
        make_one_request(i, promise);
    }

    return promise; // "I promise one day I'll be an array of responses"
};

var make_one_request = function (index, promise) {

    $.ajax({
        url : '/echo/json/', 
        dataType : 'json',
        method: 'post', // <---- I'm making a POST because this is a fiddle
                        //       you will still use a GET
        data: {}, // <-- your data here
        success: function (response) {
            // these will run out of order, but your array will be ordered
            data[index] = response;
            console.log(index);

            // if the time has come, resolve the promise
            count++;
            if (count == 10) {
                promise.resolve(data); // OK! I'm an array of responses now!
            }
        }
    });
};

// I will wait until I have an array of response data
$.when(many_requests()).then( function (data) {

    // woo!
    console.log(data); 
});
```

In particular, pay attention to the `console.log` statement in the success function. The results are being returned out of order, but your array is still being indexed in the correct order. The callback to the `then` function will only run when the promise returned by `many_requests` is resolved.

Maybe this will work for you, maybe it won't, but the really important thing is: when you encounter a new kind of programming, a new pattern, or a new technique... don't try to run away and hide in your old paradigm! Embrace what is new and interesting, learn as much as you can, and then choose the techniques you love most and keep them in your tool belt.

Comment: Ah ha ha, no this isn't the problem. The problem is (as others noticed) you are trying to use `obj` when it is already out of scope. The response object will be available inside the callback, not after it.

Comment: I want to make it synchronous. Can I access it outside